# Firebase firestore Cannot read property 'firebase' of undefined

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to create a collection called "users" but there seems to be a problem with the firebase reference , I'm using an already existing repo where I added my addUserToDb() function, in the function above called saveMessagingDeviceToken() there seems to be no problem with the firebase.

```
   <code>
// Saves the messaging device token to the datastore.
function saveMessagingDeviceToken() {
  firebase.messaging().getToken().then(function(currentToken) {
    if (currentToken) {
      console.log('Got FCM device token:', currentToken);
      // Saving the Device Token to the datastore.
      firebase.firestore().collection('fcmTokens').doc(currentToken)
          .set({uid: firebase.auth().currentUser.uid});
    } else {
      // Need to request permissions to show notifications.
      requestNotificationsPermissions();
    }
  }).catch(function(error){
    console.error('Unable to get messaging token.', error);
  });
}

    // Add the user to DB
    function addUserToDb(profilePicUrl, userName, userID){
      var db = this.firebase.firestore();
      db.collection("users").doc(userID).set({
        name: userName,
        profilePic: profilePicUrl,
        uid: userID
    })
    .then(function() {
        console.log("Document successfully written!");
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
        console.error("Error writing document: ", error);
    });
    
    }

</code>
```

The way to add is taken from https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data which is the documentation.

the full error :

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'firebase' of undefined
    at addUserToDb (main.js:115)
    at Object.authStateObserver [as next] (main.js:199)
    at subscribe.ts:104
    at subscribe.ts:233
```

Comment: Try using ```firebase.firestore();``` ```instead of this.firebase.firestore();``` at line number while getting firestore instance in addUserToDb function.

Comment: @RaghuChahar, Please post comment as answer